# Haskell and manipulating a list of tuples

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

Ok so have been faced with a problem where basically I have a been told to make a multiset, or a list of tuples. (Char,Int) and then I have to write a function that takes a item and inserts it into this list, but if there is already a matching tuple in the list it increases the Int.
i.e. i had a list [(p,2),(w,3)] and i get another w it should give [(p,2),(w,4)]
How would you go about it, i've tried

```
listAdd :: Char->Int->ListOfT -> ListOfT
listAdd c i l
    |length l == 0 =(c,i):l
    |fst l == c = (c,i+1):l
```

but this gives loads of errors, i need to remove the list element at that point and replace it with with (c,i+1), so how do i remove from the list and how to i get i+1? also how do you make a loop which will go through all the elements in a list?
And i can't use any of the import Data stuff
I know this is asking a ton but any help would be great thanks.
Neo

**Okay can this code be fiddled with so it can be used tto make tuples of any items not just chars. so i could load it up and make a list of tuples with stirngs instead, close it then load it up again and make a list of tuples of ints?**

Comment: "i had a list [(p,2),(w,3)] and i get another w it should give [(p,2),(w,4)]" so your function should have the signature `Char -> ListOfT -> ListOfT`, right?

Answer (score 3):

ok I think your idea is not bad you just have to get the details straight.

The **loop** you asked about is usually either done with recursion (as a list is a recursive structure that's a great idea) or with some higher order functions like `map`, `filter`, `foldr`, ... that will hide the recursion from you (you could say they abstract away the repeating stuff) - anway in this case I think the easiest way is just to go with what you started and use the direct recursion.

Here is a simple version (you maybe want to extent) that does the basic stuff:

```
listAdd :: Char -> [(Char,Int)] -> [(Char,Int)]
listAdd c [] = [(c,1)]
listAdd c ((c',i):xs)
  | c' == c = (c,i+1):xs
  | otherwise = (c',i) : listAdd c xs
```

as you can see the first case is very similar to what you had: if the dictionary (the second argument) is the empty list than you just add a new tuple with the char to insert and the number 1

if not then you check if the first element in the dictionary has the same character (`c'` here), if yes then you increase the count and if not you let this element stand as it is and recursively search through the rest of the dictionary.

Also note that you can use pattern matching here to not only deconstruct the dictionary into `head::tail` form but also deconstruct the head into `(..,..)` tuple parts as well.

If you want you can use a `@` in there to and get the second case a bit more concise:

```
listAdd :: Char -> [(Char,Int)] -> [(Char,Int)]
listAdd c [] = [(c,1)]
listAdd c (x@(c',i):xs)
  | c' == c   = (c,i+1):xs
  | otherwise = x : listAdd c xs
```

---

PS: in case you wondered why I did not use your `Int` argument? Because I don't know what you want to do with it if there is already a value - here is a version where I just add it to it (seems resonable):

```
listAdd :: Char -> Int -> [(Char,Int)] -> [(Char,Int)]
listAdd c i [] = [(c,i)]
listAdd c i (x@(c',i'):xs)
  | c' == c = (c,i+i'):xs
  | otherwise = x : listAdd c i xs
```

Answer (score 2):

List manipulations with just recursive functions can be indeed hard for beginners to grok, but in this case they should fit the problem nicely.

Let's start with a bit better signature and a helper.

```
type MyList = [(Char, Int)]

listAdd :: Char -> MyList -> MyList
listAdd p l = listAdd' p [] l
```

Notice that I've changed the signature to accept just `Char`; we don't need to supply the initial count, since if there are no such elements currently on the list, we'll just set it to 1 when adding a new element.

Okay, that's the basic skeleton. The helper is there just to make it easier to store the "already processed" part of the list. Let's look at it:

```
listAdd' :: Char -> MyList -> MyList -> MyList
```

First, we add the recursion end condition:

```
listAdd' p left [] = left ++ [(p, 1)]
```

This means that if we haven't found the element to replace earlier, we can just add it at the end.

```
listAdd' p left (x:right) = if p == fst x
    then left ++ [(fst x, snd x + 1)] ++ right
    else listAdd' p (left ++ [x]) right
```

Okay, so now we split up the "right" part to the first element of it and the rest. Let's look at the `if`:

- if we managed to find the element, we can end the computation by appending the rest of the list to the modified element and what we had previously
- if it's still not it, we proceed with recursion.

As an additional remark at the end, you could easily change `Char` to `Eq a => a` to allow your function to work on any type that can be directly compared, `Char` included.